# Product Topology/Continuity Confusion

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Studying some product topology, but I have a problem in my notes which is left as an exercise to think about, but I am not sure how to solve it. Help with his problem will really help me understand continuity of products on topology much better.

**Problem:** How can one prove that $$\Psi(g,h)=g(0)-h(0):C[0,1]_{\text{point convergence}}\times C[0,1]_{\text{point convergence}}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{(-)}$$ where $\mathbb{R}_{(-)}$ is the usual topology, $C[0,1]_{\text{point convergence}}$ is the pointwise convergence topology.

I have a further question which results from this question, and that is, I think that $\{(g,h):g(0)\ge h(0)\}$ is a closed subeset of 
$C[0,1]_{\text{point convergence}}\times C[0,1]_{\text{point convergence}}.$ However it frustrates me because I think I still lack alot of basic techniques and methods to show this is true. I mean I can see why this would be true, but I can formally prove it.

Can anyone please help me? I am still in the process of getting used to solving problems in topology. Seeing how to solve problems like these will help me greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the problem consists in proving that $\Psi$ is continuous. It will be enough to prove that the function $\varphi\colon C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $\varphi(g)=0$ is continuous. This is so beause if $O$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, then$$\varphi^{-1}(O)=\left\{f\in C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)\,\middle|\,f(0)\in O\right\},$$which is an open subset of $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$, by the definition of the topology of pointwise convergence.

Now, since $\Psi(g,h)=\varphi(g)-\varphi(h)$, $\Psi$ is continuous.

Can you use this approach to answer the other question?

Comment: Thank you very much you are a great help, so it seems like if we have some subset $ g(0)\ge h(0),$ then this implies that $\{(g,h): g(0)-h(0)\ge 0 \}$ which is clearly the subset of all positive functions on the product of the pointwise convergent topology (since you have shown me that $g(0)-h(0$) is also continuous)?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis I have no idea about the meaning of “if we have some subset $g(0)\geqslant h(0)$, then this implies that $\left\{(g,h)\,\middle|g(0)-h(0)\geqslant0\,\right\}$” or what a positive function is. The set $\left\{(g,h)\,\middle|g(0)-h(0)\geqslant0\,\right\}$ is closed because its complement is $\left\{(g,h)\,\middle|g(0)-h(0)<0\,\right\}$, which is open by the definition of the pointwise convergence topology

Comment: $C[0,1$] means its all continuous functions on the interval form $[0,1]$ from what I understand. Ok your reasoning makes much more sense, however I am slightly confused why is $U=\{(g,h):g(0)-h(0)<0\}$ open? Is it because we can always find some $(g,h) \in U$, such that $(g\in (g-\epsilon,g+\epsilon), h\in (h-\epsilon,h+\epsilon))?$

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Because it is $\Psi^{-1}\bigl((-\infty,0)\bigr)$ and $\Psi$ is continuous. (Please forget the “by the definition of the pointwise convergence topology” from my previous comment; it is not needed here.)

Comment: O wow, thank you very much I understood that perfectly now. Your help was very much appreciated :).

Comment: @AuroraBorealis I'm glad I could help.